# How To Access Uploads?

Tags: video, downloading, youtube

When I upload a video to YouTube and exit that tab, I can no longer get back to it later. I think this also happens with other uploads. The only way is to upload something again. So far I can only see "Downloads" in Android menu:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go into the YouTube App > Press 'Menu' > Select 'My Channel'

[image: My Channel]

You then have 3 tabs of Uploads / Favourites / Playlists

[image: Uploads]

Et Voila

Comment: I think he was talking about upload list from the mobile browser, but he better use the youtube app rather than that..

Comment: @Power-Inside I agree; he wants to see the list of files being uploaded from his device, just like he can view the list of files being downloaded to his device in the browser.

Comment: @Power-Inside This is exactly what i need to know.